# Como validar uma assinatura com uma chave privada?

Tags: java, criptografia, rsa, sha1

Eu recebo uma requisição HTTP que vem no HEADER uma assinatura (SHA1). Eu possuo, armazenado em uma String, uma chave privada. Eu preciso gerar a assinatura entre o BODY da requisição HTTP e a minha chave e comparar com a assinatura que vem no HEADER. Eu tentei da seguinte forma:

```
public static boolean checkSignature(String body, String key, String assinatura) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchProviderException, InvalidKeySpecException, InvalidKeyException, SignatureException{
       Signature sig = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withRSA");


       PublicKey pkey;

       byte encKey[] = key.getBytes();

       X509EncodedKeySpec pubKeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(encKey);

       KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");

       PublicKey pubKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(pubKeySpec);


       sig.initVerify(pubKey);  
       sig.update(body.getBytes());

       return sig.verify(assinatura.getBytes());


    }
```

No entanto, ocorre erro em keyFactory.generatePublic(pubKeySpec). A exceção java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: java.security.InvalidKeyException: invalid key format é disparada. Já tentei com SHA1withDSA também. Minha chave está em String. Preciso transformá-la para alguma outro formato? Como resolvo isso? Agradeço desde já.

Anderson

Comment: Por favor dê mais detalhes, pois está difícil entender o que está acontecendo realmente. SHA-1 é um **hash**, não uma assinatura digital (muito embora um hash costume ser a primeira etapa num algoritmo de assinatura). Além disso, chaves privadas não são usadas para verificar assinaturas, são usadas para assinar (a verificação da assinatura é feita pela chave pública). Por fim, não adianta "tentar" RSA ou DSA, é preciso usar o formato exato de chave que você tem, e o algoritmo exato de assinatura empregado. Por favor dê mais detalhes do protocolo sendo usado. Quem assinou o quê, e como?

Comment: Vou tentar melhorar. Eu recebo uma requisição HTTP assinada por um servidor. A assinatura vem no HEADER. Eu recebo como uma String em JAVA. A assinatura é gerada a partir da minha chave privada junto com o BODY da requisição. A minha chave privada está em uma String JAVA também. O que eu preciso é reproduzir essa assinatura na minha aplicação (pois eu também conheço a chave privada e o BODY) para comparar com a assinatura enviada pelo servidor que me enviou a requisição HTTP. Se as assinaturas batem, estou certo que meu documento foi assinado pelo servidor.

Comment: Não estou certo qual algoritmo é usado! Não entendo bem do assunto. No entanto, a documentação do servidor que me envia a requisição diz que a assinatura é um SHA-1. A mensagem vem algo como sha1=3f547499cabz7876cfeed... representando a assinatura.

Comment: Não é assim que a assinatura digital de chave pública funciona... Você pode assinar o mesmíssimo dado duas vezes e sair duas assinaturas completamente diferentes - e ambas válidas! Isso porque o algoritmo de assinatura é randomizado. A única maneira que conheço de verificar uma assinatura é usando a chave pública. Contudo, pelo que você está dizendo, não é uma assinatura o que está sendo enviado, e sim um hash. Isso não garante autenticidade, só ajuda na integridade. Vou tentar escrever uma resposta explicando isso.

Comment: Ok mgibsonbr! Agradeço bastante a ajuda!

Comment: Apenas para referência, a documentação do servidor mostra um exemplo de como foi feito em Ruby:

def generated_signature
  'sha1=' + OpenSSL::HMAC.hexdigest(OpenSSL::Digest.new('sha1'), secret_key, request_body)
end

Comment: Agora eu entendi do que se trata rsrs. Um HMAC é um tipo de assinatura, sim, mas uma que só pode ser verificada pela própria pessoa que assinou (já que quem verifica compartilha o mesmo segredo de quem assina). Nesse contexto, não costumamos usar o termo "chave privada", só "chave secreta" ou "chave" mesmo, pra diferenciar da criptografia assimétrica (onde há um par de chaves, uma pública e uma privada). Veja minha resposta, e preste bastante atenção nos detalhes, pois qualquer errinho vai fazer as assinaturas não baterem uma com a outra.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existe uma diferença entre assinatura via criptografia assimétrica (aquela que usa chaves pública e privada, normalmente chamada "assinatura digital") e a assinatura via criptografia simétrica. Nesta, um único valor secreto é usado tanto pra assinar quanto pra verificar a assinatura. Essa "assinatura" nesse contexto costuma ser chamada de [**Código Autenticador de Mensagens**](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autenticador_de_mensagem) (*Message Authentication Code* - MAC), e é comumente implementada com o auxílio de uma função de [*hashing*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o_hash_criptogr%C3%A1fica) - resultando em um *Hash-based Message Authentication Code* - HMAC. Segundo seu último comentário, é isso que está sendo usado pelo seu servidor.

Segundo [essa pergunta no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26690360/520779), uma maneira de gerar um HMAC (e consequentemente de verificá-lo, pois nesse caso sim basta comparar as assinaturas) seria a seguinte:

```
public static boolean checkSignature(String body, String key, String assinatura) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException {
    byte encKey[] = key.getBytes();
    SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(encKey, "HmacSHA1");

    Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA1");
    mac.init(keySpec);

    byte[] result = mac.doFinal(body.getBytes(CODIFICACAO_COMUM));

    // Compara o resultado com a assinatura, e retorna se são ou não iguais
}
```

Nota: se sua assinatura está vindo codificada em hexadecimal, é necessário [converter o resultado](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9655181/520779) (variável `result`) de um array de bytes para uma string hexadecimal antes de fazer a comparação. Ou o oposto, converter a assinatura de string para array de bytes e então comparar os arrays.

**Atenção:** `str.getBytes()` [**não é a mesma coisa**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes%28%29) que converter de/para hexadecimal, portanto tome cuidado! Além disso, `getBytes` usa a codificação padrão da plataforma, que pode não ser a mesma no cliente e no servidor (ex.: se seu servidor for Linux e seu cliente for Windows o texto será assinado em UTF-8 e verificado em Cp1252, e os resultados não vão ser iguais).

Comment: Caro mgibsonbr, funcionou certinho! Converti result para hexadecimal e bateu com a assinatura! Muito obrigado! Ajudou bastante!!!

Comment: @user2826942 Que bom! Não se esqueça de testar com arquivos acentuados também, só pra ter certeza que o *encoding* está ok.